# Virtual Host: JavaScript file not found when exists

Tags: javascript, apache, virtualhost

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I have created a virtual host in "etc/apache2/sites-available" with the name "canvas.local.conf"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName canvas.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/canvas
    <Directory /var/www/canvas>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

And I have created an "index.html" file with these content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo Canvas</title>
        <!--[if lte IE8]><script src = "./javascript/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <style>
            #canvas{
                width: 640px;
                height: 400px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
            }
        </style>
        <script src = "./javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                alert("Page loaded");
            });         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the directory "javascript" exists the files "excanvas.js" and "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"

So, when I access to the page through "http://canvas.local" I can see the page loaded, but the server doesn't find the file "jquery-1.11.1.min.js". And this file exists in the directory.

Comment: if you go to http://canvas.local/javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js do you get the javascript file or a 404?

Comment: If I go to http://canvas.local/javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js I've got an error 404 :(

Comment: @JoséCarlos what's the directory structure of your app?

Comment: The directory structure is ... <br />

/var/www/canvas --> index.html<br />
/var/www/canvas/javascript --> jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: josecarlos@R2D2:/var/www/canvas$ ls -R<br />
.:<br />
index.html  index.html~  javascript<br />

./javascript:<br />
excanvas.js  jquery-1.11.1.min.js<br />

Comment: Maybe file permissions not in order?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  673 ago 19 08:38 index.html<br/>-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 95786 ago 19 08:38 jquery-1.11.1.min.js They've got the same permissions ... Sorry, but I don't know how to make a line break :(

Comment: `josecarlos@R2D2:/var/www$ ls -Rl canvas
canvas:
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  673 ago 19 08:38 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  694 ago 19 08:38 index.html~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 ago 19 01:46 javascript

canvas/javascript:
total 124
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27045 ago 19 08:38 excanvas.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 95786 ago 19 08:38 jquery-1.11.1.min.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian (and some others) add a global alias for /javascript/ pointing to /usr/share/javascript
then you can't use a directory /javascript in your document root (or you must redeclare it)

see https://packages.debian.org/stable/javascript-common

Comment: Thanks @bastien-durel I have changed the name of directory "javascript" to "js" and ... It works!!! The solution is to change the name of the directory "javascript" to "js" for example. Thanks Bastien and all other people who can try to help me

Comment: You can add your own alias in the vhost to don't change the name : "Alias /javascript /var/www/canvas/javascript"